# HTML pages are not rendering

Tags: python, html, forms, flask, wtforms

I'm currently working on a 100 days of code project however I'm stuck. I'm unable to render the "Success.html" and "Denied.html" templates in my login route code. I'm including the python and html portions of the code. Any insight is appreciated. I think the problem is inside the login route code however I've hit a wall and don't know what to try at the moment.

```
import email_validator
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from flask_wtf.csrf import CSRFProtect
from wtforms.validators import Email, Length, DataRequired, ValidationError
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField
from email_validator import validate_email

# create a flask instance
app = Flask(__name__)

# CSRF protection
app.secret_key = "123456"
#disabling CSRF Protection
# app.config['WTF_CSRF_ENABLED'] = False


# create a form class
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    def validate_email(self, field):
        # Custom email validation using email_validator
        try:
            validate_email(field.data)
        except Exception as e:
            raise ValidationError(str(e))

    email = StringField(label="Email", validators=[DataRequired(), Email()], render_kw={"size": 30})
    password = PasswordField(label="Password", validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=8)], render_kw={"size": 30})
    submit = SubmitField(label="Log In")


# create a route decorator
@app.route('/', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    form.validate_on_submit()
    print(request.method)
    print(form.email.data)
    print(form.password.data)

    return render_template('login.html', form=form)


@app.route('/login', methods=["GET", "POST"])
def login_info():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        if form.email.data == "admin@email.com" and form.password.data == "12345678":
            print(request.method)
            print(type(form.email.data))
            print(type(form.password.data))
            return render_template('success.html')
        else:
            return render_template('denied.html')
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The HTML code for the login page is this

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <h1>Login Page</h1>
        <form method="post" action="{{ url_for('login')}}" novalidate>
    {{form.csrf_token}}
    <p>
        {{form.email.label}} <br> {{form.email}}
        {% for err in form.email.errors %}
        <span style="color:red">{{ err }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    <p>
        {{form.password.label}} <br> {{form.password}}
        {% for err in form.password.errors %}
        <span style="color:red">{{ err  }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </p>
    {{form.submit}}
        </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What error messages do you get or what happens that you are not expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting the html 'success.html' to render when I input the correct email and password. What's happening instead is the 'login.html' renders.

Answer (score 1):

You're submitting your form to the wrong endpoint. The form's `action` attribute references `login`, not `login_info`.

Answer (score 0):

Typically you'll want the `GET` to the login view to just provide the form (`login.html`) and the `POST` to processes the submitted login details and then redirect the user where you want them to go (or just show `success.html` in your case).

You've somewhat complicated things by having 2 views that both take `GET` and `POST` but the `login_info` one isn't referenced anywhere in your `login.html` so it's never actually used.  The `login` view calls `.validate_on_submit()` but then always just returns the `login.html` and that's why you don't ever see `success.html`.